# How do the words "stare" and "gaze" change the meaning of the sentence in the given context?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Please consider the excerpt below.

> I felt awkward discussing such issues with Aarti’s dad, so I kept quiet.
>   “I know how the education business works, Tiwari talks intellectual,
>   but he wants his share. I hope you guys won’t get me involved with that.”
>   “Not at all, sir,” I said. “Even I don’t deal with that stuff. I only look after the college.”
>   “So all such work is done by Shukla-ji’s men?” Aarti’s father asked.
>   “Yes,” I said, as I ***_*___** at the floor.

I need little help how the words *stare* and *gaze* changes the meaning of sentence in the given context. Please find below the dictionary (ODO) meanings of those words:

> **[Stare](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stare)** = look fixedly or vacantly at someone or something with one’s eyes wide open.
>   **[Gaze](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gaze)** = look steadily and intently, especially in admiration, surprise, or thought.

Comment: I've given an answer, but this still feels like writing advice. There is a fine line between word-choice and ghost-writing, and I'm not sure which side these requests fall. Perhaps it depends on their frequency. (And as a free gift I've done some proof-reading, which is definitely off-topic. Notice how the quotation marks are paired, and the added possessive apostrophes.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thank you so much. I am under the impression that the help related to differences in meanings of the words can get from ELU. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose "I" (is that still Gopal?) is feeling awkward or embarrassed and looking downwards to avoid meeting Aarti's father's eye.

In such an instance, the idiom is to ***stare*** at the floor. From the dictionary definitions you give, Gopal is looking fixedly at the floor, probably at a particular point. A *gaze* is less focused; Gopal would gaze at Aarthi across a crowded room — it's the *admiration or thought* part of the definition which makes the difference.

Answer (score 2):

The Cambridge online dictionary provides the following meanings of the two words:

Stare - to look for a long time with the eyes wide open, especially when surprised, frightened or thinking

Gaze - to look at something or someone for a long time, especially in surprise, admiration or because you are **thinking about something else**

So, according to these definitions, staring would be more appropriate, because the guy isn't thinking about anything **else**, rather he is not comfortable looking Aarti's dad in the eye.

Answer (score -1):

I think "gaze" would be more appropriate in this context. Stare has a feeling of "focus" and I guess in this context *I* would like to focus on *what Aartis dad is saying*. So when *I* am looking at the floor here, it has a sense that although *I* am looking at the floor but I am not focusing or giving my full attention to it, just ***gazing*** at it absentmindedly.